# text-decoration:none formatting not working when sending HTML emails with Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, outlook-2007

If I attempt to send the following html email from Outlook 2007 the hyperlink shows when I receive it in gmail. However, sending it from an online test service the hyperlink does not show. If I reply from gmail to the outlook 2007 client, outlook shows the email without the hyperlink, as intended.

It seems to me that on the outgoing email outlook is attaching its own stylesheet that is overriding this. Is there any way to add to my code to stop this? I've tried the important! trick to no avail.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<div>
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="www.example.com"><font color="#e4480d"><span style='text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>www.example.com</span></font></a>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook processes your HTML before sending it out, so it does alter your code pretty heavily in fact. If you do inspect element in Chrome on the the email in GMail you should see that there are all sorts of new tags with classes like "MsoNormal". They also probably throw another `<a>` tag in there too.

You'll notice that when you receive a plain text link in Outlook it does that same blue hyperlink. It's the same thing, it's just putting the `<a>` around your link inside your `span` and `font` tags and overriding them.

My (partial) solution would be to see if there's a `class` on the `<a>` and do the `text-decoration:none` in the style tag on that class. Since GMail doesn't support `<style>` or linked stylesheets, I think you're out of luck if you want to customize your link colors and still send from Outlook :(

There's always the option of not sending from Outlook though! You could use your domain's IMAP settings and use GMail's interface to send and receive mail. See below:

https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018,1665137,2769074

Answer (score -1):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can read more about that in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope that you will find the answer there.

Comment: According to the capabilities the a element has full CSS support for the style attribute - so it should be able to be altered if I'm understanding this table correctly.

Comment: Why do you keep posting links to Microsoft documentation as answers? What makes you think they would document Word's terrible CSS support and HTML processing?